# Geometric and linear independence in affine and linear spaces (Proof Validation)

Tags: affine-geometry, linear-independence

I am looking to prove the following statement:

> Let $\{a_i\}^n_{i=0} \subseteq L$ be a set of points, then we have
>
> $\{a_i\}^n_{i=0}$ is geometrically independent $\Longleftrightarrow \{a_i - a_0\}^n_{i=1}$  is linearly independent

Before going into the proof, I'll state for being complete **geometrical independence**

> A set of points $\{a_i\}^n_{i=0} \subseteq L$ is called geometrically independent if for any scalar $\gamma_i$ it holds
> \begin{equation}
>     \sum_{i=0}^n \gamma_i = 0 \;\; \land \;\; \sum_{i=0}^n \gamma_i a_i = 0 \;\;\Longrightarrow \;\; \gamma_0 = \gamma_1 = \dots = \gamma_n = 0
> \end{equation}

**Proof:**

> Let $\{(a_i, \gamma_i)\}_{i=0}^n$ be a set of weighted geometrically independent points.
> We have
>
> \begin{align}
> \sum_{i=0}^n \gamma_i a_i &= 0 \\
> \sum_{i=1}^n \gamma_i a_i + \gamma_0 a_0 &= 0
> \end{align}
> Note, $a_i$ are geometrically independent, hence $\gamma_0 = \ldots = \gamma_n = 0$, we can write
> \begin{align}
> \sum_{i=1}^n \gamma_i a_i - \sum_{i=1}^n \gamma_i a_0 = 0\\
> \sum_{i=1}^n \gamma_i a_i - \gamma_i a_0 = 0\\
> \sum_{i=1}^n \gamma_i (a_i - a_0) = 0\\
> \end{align}

Is this direct proof sufficient for the equivalence statement, i.e. does it show both directions sufficiently, since we can go top-down/bottom-up?